# is there open source sdk for push server android

Tags: android, push-notification

I am newbie in android. I am looking for  open source sdk for push server. I do googling a lot and find [openmobster](http://www.openmobster.com/push.html) but it need JBOSS and wrote with java. I need source code or open source sdk for php because my server wrote with Php and I dont want to use PushWoosh,GCM and ... for this. I need a push server open source. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been writing my own push server for some time now. And if I can tell you anything, it'd be this...
***Don't use PHP for this***. You may think you can write a great streaming HTTP server with Apache but it will just suck the battery dry and consume a ton of network bandwidth. You may as well make a polling system instead.

I wrote my server in Java. It supports async sockets and encryption. I suppose you can do it in C or C++ too but I'm good with Java and I suspect Java would be easier for this kind of thing.

So, in conclusion, use Java or C or something other than PHP. That's not what it's designed for. Opt for a language that is versatile in what you want it to do. OpenMobster may be what you want.